# VB Class in App_Code folder cannot access VB Class in root folder

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a public VB class in the root folder of the project called Contact.vb and another VB class in the App_Code folder called Service.vb.

If I try to declare the Contact class in Service.vb like this:

```
Dim ds As New Contact
```

I get this error while compiling:

> Type 'Contact' is not defined.

I am used to C# coding, so I don't really understand what I'm missing here...

EDIT #1:

Here is the first part of the Contact class. The class has been generated based on a schema.

```
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <autogenerated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version: 1.1.4322.2300
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
'     the code is regenerated.
' </autogenerated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml


<Serializable(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(true)>  _
Public Class Contact
    Inherits DataSet

    Private tableContact As ContactDataTable
```

EDIT #2:
I finally found out what was wrong. If I build the project in VS while in administrator mode it builds successfully, but it fails if I'm not in administrator mode.

I'm not sure why it is like this, but I guess it may be because of folder permissions or something similar.

Comment: is it included in the project or just in the folder?

Comment: can you post the first few lines of Contact?  The prj folders are just for organizing large projects, forms, classes, etc.  They should not matter as long as the file/class is in the prj

Comment: If it is in the project and there is no typo in the name, it should work. If you right click it in solution explorer, is there an Exclude or Include option?

Comment: Yes, the "Exlude from project" option is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong. If I build the project in VS while in administrator mode it builds successfully, but it fails if I'm not in administrator mode.

I'm not sure why it is like this, but I guess it may be because of folder permissions or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is no typo in your class? Are you able to Build / Run the project if you take out the line:

```
Dim ds As New Contact
```

I tried your class as:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <autogenerated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version: 1.1.4322.2300
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
'     the code is regenerated.
' </autogenerated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml


<Serializable(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough(), _
 System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(True)> _
Public Class Contact
    Inherits DataSet

    'Private tableContact As ContactDataTable

End Class
```

And then managed to use the Dim ds... line without any errors.

I did have a similar issue before which I sorted out by Rebuilding the solution.

Have you tried closing and reopening VS?

Comment: Nope, there are no typos, but I tried to copy the Contact class into the App_Code folder, and then it worked.

Comment: Ah, from your question I assumed that it was already there :)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is an web application or a website ?

There are many difference between the behavior of App_Code folder in this two cases...

If you use this approach in C#, normally in vb.net there are no difference.

Another thing : in c# the namespaces are created by visual studio by default, in vb.net (if I remember properly) not.